# Format option not available in 11.10 as in 10.10?

Tags: 11.10, 10.10, usb, usb-drive, format

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop and Ubuntu 10.10 on my desktop.

In 10.10 there is an option to format a pen-drive by right-clicking the icon for the pen drive and selecting format, but I am unable to find it in 11.10.

There are tools for that... But isn't there any default tool available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use  Disk Managment that you can  find from the Dash (Dash > Disk managment). From there you can do what you want

Answer (score 1):

Or also you can install `gnome-format` and it will appear in "My Computer" by right-clicking the device for installing it. Just run these commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-format
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, there is a quicklist option that is supposed to be getting added to the 12.04 release that will allow you to right click on the drive when it shows up in your panel giving you a format option.

Check it out here:
https://code.launchpad.net/~andyrock/unity/fix-814610/+merge/76857

and a picture here:
http://people.ubuntu.com/~andyrock/Format.png

This will be a much welcomed feature although I do have to say I wished it used gparted instead of 'Disk Utility'.

Answer (score 0):

Install Nautilus Actions Extra in Ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04, use the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions-extra
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu there is many method by which you can format your pendrive

**1 - by Disk utility**  [see the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1p47CLgRd6Y&feature=youtu.be)   // simplest way

---

**2-  by Gparted tool**   [see the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IloEDkHHkAs&feature=youtu.be)

// you can install it from Ubuntu software center
or 
you can install is by typing

> sudo apt-get install gparted

---

**3- by using Terminal** [see the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6TEh762Vec)

go to super mode by typing "su" followed by super mode password

> fdisk -l

that will show all the volume in your pc or you can also use the

> df

to see the usb flash drive suppose it may be /deb/sdb1

> umount /dev/sdb1

that un mount the drive

> mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1

to format drive into fat32 format